# Question about real number for Tomcat's max-threads

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

Tomcat provides some attributes in order to configure the amount of requests your application will be capable to handle.
The first one I'm talking about is `maxThreads`. It's said in the docs that the default value is 200 and if more requests come in, it will be stacked up in a queue which the default value is 100. In theory, if the number of requests go higher than 300, it should start rejecting requests but it's not what is actually happening.

I've tried even to drop this numbers to 10 for `maxThreads` and 10 for the `acceptCount`, but Tomcat actually doesn't reject more requests.

What am I missing on these settings? I also tried to decrease the number of `max-connections` but nothing happens as I expect as per the docs.

Here is the settings I'm am currently using for a Spring Boot application within the `application.yml` (I've also tried running a pure tomcat with a plain standard war):

```
server.tomcat:
  max-threads: 10
  accept-count: 10
  max-connections: 10
```

Comment: How have you verified that Tomcat in fact has exceeded its buffer?

Comment: I am just taking into account the values for the attributes mentioned. In order to monitor the application I was using Visual VM. That allowed myself to check all the threads (`nio-8080-exec-n` threads) and their state. So when I was sending 500 requests per minute through my JMeter project, I could see a moment where all threads were blocked and new requests weren't rejected. I am using a mechanism to block the threads intentionally because I want to exhaust the thread pool. The way I am doing that is irrelevant, by the way.

Comment: How long are you blocking threads? Is keep-alive enabled on both sides? Regardless of Visual VM results at any instant, did jmeter test ended successfully?

Comment: @LuisMuños, keep-alive is enabled on both sides. Regardless of the results of JMeter (which I am mostly using just to smash my service with requests), when I see all threads from Tomcat's thread pool blocked, if I send a new request using cURL, the request made with cURL isn't rejected.